# DataProvider is not getting called

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I am using TestNG. I have set the DataProvider and control is skipping the DataProvider. Below are the steps that I have followed

1. Package “testCase”, class “Login_ATC01”, static method “login_FR()”.

   ```
   @Test  
   public static void Login_FR()       
   {   
       CommonModules.fn_setUpEnv();
       Login.fn_SignUp();
   }
   ```

This class has imported package containing class CommonModules and Login

2. Method fn_SignUp() is inside class “Login” inside package “automation”

package automation

```
public class Login {

@Test
public static void fn_SignUp()
{
    String sUserName = "";
    String sPassword = "";
    //Authentication();
    fn_mainLogin(sUserName,sPassword);
}

@Test(dataProvider="Authentication")
public static void fn_mainLogin(String sUserName, String sPassword)
{

    if(Login_Objects.txtbx_Email().isDisplayed())
    {
            Login_Objects.txtbx_Email().sendKeys(sUserName);           
            Login_Objects.txtbx_Password().sendKeys(sPassword);              
            Login_Objects.txtbx_Password().submit();
    }
}

@DataProvider(name="Authentication")     
public static Object[][] Authenticate()  throws Exception
{
    // Setting up the Test Data Excel file
    ExcelUtils.setExcelFile("/Users/abc/workspace/Test_Auto/src/testData/TestData.xlsx","Sheet1");
    ..
    ..
    Object[][] testObjArray = ExcelUtils.getTableArray("/Users/abc/workspace/Test_Auto/src/testData/TestData.xlsx","Sheet1",iTestCaseRow);
    return (testObjArray);
}
}
```

Class Login has dataProvider “Authentication”, which should be called @Test on method fn_mainLogin. When fn_mainLogin is called from fn_SignUp, dataProvider “Authentication” is not getting called. While debugging, control does not get transferred to dataProvider and username and password fields are null.

Comment: `@Test` methods are not supposed to be static. Could you try to remove static on test methods and tell me what happens?

Comment: Thanks for the info! Then do you mean I should create object to access fn_mainLogin() and fn_SignUp() ? I am new to TestNG, read articles and saw videos where they just run the classes directly as 1 testcase. SO any help is appreciated.

Comment: I will try with constructors and get back to you.

Comment: No need of constructor. Just remove `static` from `@Test` methods. I think you should read the documentation too: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: I created a sample test case with dataProvider and had @Test as static, but they worked.  I will read the doc and try to investigate further. Thanks much!!